# save() method is not working in django after receiveing all the data?

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

The data are coming from a filed where i want to update only specific data that comes other wise left the model data as previous. So in my views the code is like this:

**views.py**

```
def set_product_detail(request, id):
    id = int(id)
    keys = [
        "name",
        "price",
        "digital",
        "image",
        "image1",
        "image2",
        "image3",
        "seller",
        "stock",
        "size",
        "color",
        "search_tags",
        "description",
    ]
    if request.method == "POST":
        real_keys = []
        for each in keys:
            if each.startswith("image"):
                if request.FILES.get(each) is not None:
                    real_keys.append(each)
            else:
                if request.POST[each] is not None:
                    real_keys.append(each)

        print(real_keys)

        product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
        print(product)
        for keys in real_keys:
            if keys.startswith("image"):
                product.keys = request.FILES.get(keys)
                print(keys, product.keys)

            else:
                product.keys = request.POST[keys]
                print(keys, product.keys)
        product.save()
    return redirect("view_product_in_table")
```

**models.py**

```
class Product(models.Model):

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    price = models.FloatField()
    digital = models.BooleanField(default=False, null=True, blank=True)
    image = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    image1 = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    image2 = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    image3 = models.ImageField(null=True, blank=True)
    seller = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    distance = models.CharField(max_length=5, null=True)
    stock = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    color = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    description = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True)
    size = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    search_tags = models.CharField(max_length=100, null=True)
    created_at = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
```

The provided keys are the fields in Product table!
The print method print these after saving the form!

```
['name', 'price', 'digital', 'image', 'seller', 'stock', 'size', 'color', 'search_tags', 'description']
Facewash
name Facewash
price 12000.0
digital False
image beardoil_B1MQvb0.jpeg
seller Usha Cosmetics
stock 12
size 250 Ml
color Green Packet
search_tags men, grooming ,facewash, fashion , makeups
description Anti Oil Facewash for Oily Skin
```

But that product.save() is not working ! And my db is not being updated !

Comment: Please post your Product model definition. Have you run makemigrations and migrate? I had this issue when I had not migrated my db properly.

Comment: @AbdurRehmanKhan yes i have migrated and there seems no change detected while migrating again !

Comment: Are you expecting the product.keys to become product.name, product.price etc? Because it's not going to work that way. product.keys = something is just creating an attribute for the Product class. Instead of that line try adding  something hardcoded like product.name = "test" and then run the code. If it works then this line is your issue.

Comment: Actually I may be wrong... it looks like product.keys is indeed working according to the print statement.

Comment: what is .keys is it a related Keys model?

Comment: @AbdurRehmanKhan yes you can see the product.keys are returning the value !

Comment: @iklinac , the keys are the fields of model , and i am hardcoding them using a for loop in the list (real_keys) that contains all the field name.

Answer (score 0):

I was accessing the model fields with the variable which seems not working. So , i did changed these things in my views:

**views.py**

```
 product = Product.objects.get(id=id)
    fields = product.__dict__
    print(product)
    for keys in real_keys:
        if keys.startswith("image"):
            fields[keys] = request.FILES.get(keys)

        else:
            fields[keys] = request.POST[keys]

    product.save()
```

> Get the fields name in dict and update them ! Now it seems to be working.